# Is "Step out from behind" a phrasal verb?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

Look at these examples:

```
He stepped out from behind the curtain.
Step out from behind the counter.
Step out from behind the blue wall.
Step out from behind the veil of illusion.
```

Comment: This is a beauty. Three single cohesion levels, two double, and the triple to consider. (c) 'came from the park / behind the counter' indicates no great cohesion between _from_ & _behind_. (a) 'stepped from behind the counter' and 'rolled out from behind the counter' suggest little cohesion between _step_ and _out_ (in this case). (b) 'out from' looks quite cohesive, and 'in to' is usually fused. However, this doesn't have a bearing on whether or not we are dealing with a MWV here. So, 'no'.

Comment: See also: "[The sentence with the most prepositions at its end](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20417)". "What did you bring that book that I don't want to be read to from out of about 'Down Under' up for?"

Answer (score 4):

To me, *step out from behind* sounds literal in meaning. Each of the modifiers takes on a literal meaning: **Step** (literally taking steps). **Out** (away from the region that is "behind" some object of reference). **From** (away from the region or object of reference). **Behind** (origin of movement path). In other words, no, I do not see it as a phrasal verb.